# best way to get current objec before update - put api platform

Tags: php, symfony4, api-platform.com

I created a put operation to my Orders class. I need to check if the order is canceled (status: 5) before updating the object. I need to get the current object (like it is in the database) to know the difference between them.

```
public function __invoke(Orders $data): JsonResponse
    {

        return $this->handle($data);
    }

    public function handle(Orders $order){
        $order->setCreatedDate(new \DateTime());
        $em->persist($order);
        $em->flush();
        return new JsonResponse($order);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in the event `EventPriorities::POST_VALIDATE` and you are making sure that the new data has been validated.

I'm suppose that you use the class `Orders` in order to get in the event subscriber the old data you must get the attribute `previous_data`

```
<?php

use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;


class OrderSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array The event names to listen to
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => [
                ['isOrderCancelled', EventPriorities::POST_VALIDATE],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function isOrderCancelled(ViewEvent $event)
    {
        if(
            in_array($event->getRequest()->getMethod(), ['PUT', 'PATCH']) &&
            ($data = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('previous_data')) instanceof Orders
        ) {
            // Clone and save the original object for further use and checks.
            $this->saveData($data);
        }
    }
}
```

The method `saveData` it's not implemented but you can implement to do with the old data that you need.

In this method you can access too to the new deserialized and validated data, There're two ways, boths returns the new object with modified data.

- `$event->getRequest()->attributes->get('data'))`
- `$event->getControllerResult()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the event system](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/) to accomplish this.

In this example I presume you used an entity called `Order`

```
/**
 * @ApiResource
 */
class Order {
    ...
}
```

```
<?php

use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;


class OrderSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array The event names to listen to
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => [
                ['isOrderCancelled', EventPriorities::PRE_VALIDATE],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function isOrderCancelled(ViewEvent $event)
    {
        // first check if this affects the requested resource
        $resource = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_api_resource_class');

        if (Order::class !== $resource) {
            return;
        }

        // second check if this is the put_item controller
        $controller = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller');

        if ('api_platform.action.put_item' !== $controller) {
            return;
        }

        // third fetch the object instance
        $order = $event->getControllerResult();

        // you can throw an exception if you order is already cancelled. Or something along those lines
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the `$order = $event->getControllerResult();` returns the serialized object but I'm pretty sure that what it's asked is how to get the previous entity (the one which is going to be updated). Example we want to change B into B" , we need to check something on B before flushing B".